# Lock file in unix(Solaris)

Tags: c, файлы, unix, exec, solaris

Вопрос следующий: в `man`-е Solaris написано, что захват файлов наследуется при `exec`, однако, когда я захватываю файл на запись, а затем вызываю `execlp(...)` — открываю файл в редакторе. Затем я создаю новую сессию и запускаю ту же программу, по идее процесс должен остановиться в ожидании из-за флага `F_SETLKW` в `fcntl()`, но он также открывает редактор... В чем может быть дело?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define editor "nano"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct flock lock;
    int fd;

    if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR)) == -1) {
            perror("Cannot open file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    lock.l_start = 0;
    lock.l_len = 0;

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock) == -1) {
            perror("fcntl failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    execlp(editor, editor, argv[1], NULL);
    perror("exec is not working");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

Comment: `lock` используется частично неинициализированная, ее следует обнулить перед использованием. А вообще раз тут не происходит создания нового процесса, то переблокировка происходит с использованием ранее установленного блокиратора. Т.е. этот код эквивалентен вызову `fcntl` с одними и теми же параметрами несколько раз подряд.

Comment: @VTT, неинициализированы только выходные поля и, очевидно, проблему это не решает... ЗЫ: на linux'е тоже самое...

Comment: Надо бы посмотреть в таблице файлов в /proc с чем связан этот fd после переключения на nano (может он закрывает дескрипторы и открывая файлы по новой их использует?)

Comment: нет, дескриптор открыт и связан с заданным файлом... у меня создаётся впечатление, что `man`'ы всё же могут врать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, блокировка действительно наследуется, проблема в редакторе. Если заменить вызываемую программу в exec и поставить флаг `F_SETLK`, то выдается ошибка, как и положено. Но не могу понять, что редактор такого делает...

Comment: @user276153, и правда, похоже проблема в том, что редактор открывает тот же самый файл ещё раз: если передать ему другой файл, то всё работает как и ожидалось...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **man 2 fcntl (Solaris)**
>
> All locks associated with a file for a given process are removed when **a file descriptor for that file** is closed by that process or the process holding that file descriptor terminates

В linux этот момент расписан более подробно:

> **man 2 fcntl (Linux [`man-pages-ru`])**
>
> - Если процесс закрывает любой файловый дескриптор, ссылающийся на файл, то освобождаются все блокировки процесса для этого файла, независимо от файлового дескриптора(ов), на который получена блокировка.  Это  плохо:  это
>           означает, что процесс может потерять свои блокировки на файл, такой как `/etc/passwd` или `/etc/mtab`, когда какой-либо причине библиотечная функция решает их открыть, прочитать и закрыть.

В данном случае происходит следующее: `nano` открывает тот же файл, на который удерживается блокировка (на другом дескрипторе), читает его и закрывает. В момент закрытия блокировка теряется, как и описано выше.

Comment: в том то и дело, что файл не закрывается, прочтите внимательно вопрос. В программе ставится блокировка с помощью `fcntl`, выполняется `exec(nano..)`, процесс не завершается, затем в новой сессии запускается эта же программа, и тут-то процесс должен перейти в ожидание, т.к. блокировка уже стоит....

Comment: @user276153, тот же самый файл (`argv[1]`) передаётся в аргументах `exec()`'а в `nano`, после чего `nano` уже сам делает `open()`→`read()`→**`close()`**. Вот этот самый `close()`, хотя он и работает с другим fd на тот же файл, и убивает блокировку.

Comment: Круто! А я-то всегда недоумевал, почему для локинга используют отдельный файл

Comment: @avp, но как тогда открыть файл и при этом не потерять блокировку, чем поможет отдельный файл?

Comment: @user276153, с блокировкой на другом файле `close ()` на редактируемом не будет интерферировать с оной... ЗЫ: в соляре, на сколько я понимаю, других блокировок нет? `flock ()` — это просто обёртка к `fcntl()`?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, других нет блокировок, на самом деле, не понятно, зачем так сделали. Сейчас пробую с `link-ами` что-нибудь сообразить...

Comment: @Fat-Zer обсолютно прав, блокировку можно использовать внутри программы на одном и том же открытом файловом дескрипторе, тогда это работает. Например в мультитредовом исполнении, чтобы ограничить запись/чтение файла из разных тредов. На уровне системы и разных приложений это использовать не рекомендуется.

Comment: @user276153, в общем-то Fat-Zer уже объяснил. Ну, например, создайте каталог `/tmp/my-nano-locks/` и в нем делаете файлы с именем, сделанным из inode и devno того файла,  что передаете `nano` (на самом деле тут будет довольно много мороки с удалением таких старых файлов) и делаете лок на этот файл. Я думаю, такая схема будет работать

Comment: @user276153, вы удивляетесь почему так сделали? Хороший вопрос. Видимо потому, что id владельца лока хранится в общей таблице открытых файлов, а там уже нет связи с fd в процессе, через который лок был получен. Поэтому любой close этого файла владельцем  лока убивает лок. Видимо исправление такого поведение тянет за собой слишком много переделок, ухудшает производительность и т.п.